# Data not loaded by the ajax and data modal

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to loaded the vehicle details using ajax and data modal dialog. but seem that the data does not loaded correctly and i cant seem to figured out what is wrong with codes.

```
<div class="container" style="width:900px;">  
    <h3 align="center">View All Available Vehicle</h3>  
    <br />  
    <div class="table-responsive">  
         <table class="table table-striped">  
              <tr>  
                   <th width="40%">Plate Number</th>
                   <th width="20%">Type</th>
                   <th width="20%">Status</th>  
                   <th width="10%">View</th>  
              </tr>  
              <?php  
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
              {  
              ?>  
              <tr>  
                   <td><?php echo $row["plateNo_vehicle"]; ?></td> 
                   <td><?php echo $row["vehicle_Type"];?></td> 
                   <td><?php echo $row["vehicle_status"];?></td>
                   <td><input type="button" name="view" value="more" id="<?php echo $row["id_vehicle"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>  
              </tr>  
              <?php  
              }  
              ?>  
         </table>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

data modal dialog used to display the details.

```
<div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
  <div class="modal-dialog">  
       <div class="modal-content">  
            <div class="modal-header">  
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Vehicles Details</h4>  
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-body" id="vehicle_detail">  
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-footer">  
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
            </div>  
       </div>  
  </div>
```

this is the select.php that i used

```
<?php 

   if(isset($_POST["vehicle_id"])) {  
      $output = '';  
      $link=msqli_connect("localhost","root","root","vms");
      $query = "SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE id_vehicle = '".$_POST["vehicle_id"]."'";  
      $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);  
      $output .= '  
      <div class="table-responsive">  
           <table class="table table-bordered">';  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td width="30%"><label>Plate No</label></td>  
                     <td width="70%">'.$row["plateNo_vehicle"].'</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                     <td width="30%"><label>Engine Number</label></td>  
                     <td width="70%">'.$row["engineNo_vehicle"].'</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                     <td width="30%"><label>Engine Capacity</label></td>  
                     <td width="70%">'.$row["engineCapacity_vehicle"].'</td>  
                </tr>  
                ';  
      }  
      $output .= "</table></div>";  
      echo $output;  
   }  

 ?>
```

script used

```
<script>  

$(document).ready(function(){  
   $('.view_data').click(function(){  
       var vehicle_id = $(this).attr("id_vehicle");  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"select.php",  
            method:"post",  
            data:{vehicle_id:vehicle_id},  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#vehicle_detail').html(data);  
                 $('#dataModal').modal("show");  
            }  
       });   
   });   
});   

</script>
```

Comment: How is it not getting loaded correctly? Is data coming in but displayed wrong?

Comment: it just pop up the empty data modal

Comment: What did you get in response of ajax call ?

Comment: the data modal dialog does show up, but it only display the header and the close button..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your select.php file:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST["vehicle_id"])) {  
$output = '';  
$link=msqli_connect("localhost","root","root","vms"); <========
```

*TYPO*. It should've been:

```
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","vms");
```

**Also**,

Add a `data-vehicleid` attribute to your `view_data` button:

```
<td><input type="button" data-vehicleid="<?php echo $row["id_vehicle"]; ?>" name="view" value="more" id="<?php echo $row["id_vehicle"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data " /></td>
```

And then change your script to receive that attribute value:

```
<script>  

$(document).ready(function(){  
   $('.view_data').click(function(){  
       var vehicle_id = $(this).attr("data-vehicleid");  <=====
       $.ajax({  
           ....
       }); 
   });  
});  


</script>
```

Right now, you've set it to :

```
var vehicle_id = $(this).attr("id_vehicle");
```

which won't work as you don't have an attribute called `id_vehicle="..."` on that button. I'm guessing you meant attr("id");

Comment: Edited the answer, do let us know if it worked with the modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on your `while loop`

```
 <?php  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
        {  
?>  
<tr>  
   <td><?php echo $row["plateNo_vehicle"]; ?></td> 
   <td><?php echo $row["vehicle_Type"];?></td> 
   <td><?php echo $row["vehicle_status"];?></td>
   <td><input type="button" name="view" value="more" data-vehicle-id="<?php echo $row["id_vehicle"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>  
</tr>  
<?php  
  }  
?>
```

And in script change your id `var vehicle_id = $(this).attr("data-vehicle-id");`
Hope this code work

Answer (score 0):

in order to get the id of this this you need to add onclick

```
<td><input type="button" name="view" value="more" id="<?php echo $row["id_vehicle"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" onclick="getId(this.id)"/></td>  

function getId(clicked_id){
   var vehicle_id = clicked_id;
      $.ajax({  
        url:"select.php",  
        method:"post",  
        data:{vehicle_id:vehicle_id},  
        success:function(data){  
             $('#vehicle_detail').html(data);  
             $('#dataModal').modal("show");  
        }  
   });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is updated code for view:

**view:**

```
<div class="container" style="width:900px;">  
    <h3 align="center">View All Available Vehicle</h3>  
    <br />  
    <div class="table-responsive">  
         <table class="table table-striped">  
              <tr>  
                   <th width="40%">Plate Number</th>
                   <th width="20%">Type</th>
                   <th width="20%">Status</th>  
                   <th width="10%">View</th>  
              </tr>  
              <?php  
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
              {  
              ?>  
              <tr>  
                   <td><?php echo $row["plateNo_vehicle"]; ?></td> 
                   <td><?php echo $row["vehicle_Type"];?></td> 
                   <td><?php echo $row["vehicle_status"];?></td>
                   <td><a href="#" title="more details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dataModal" data-vehicle_id="<?php echo $row["id_vehicle"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">more</a></td>  
              </tr>  
              <?php  
              }  
              ?>  
         </table>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
$('#dataModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var vehicle_id = button.data('vehicle_id')

    var modal = $(this)

   $.ajax({  
        url:"select.php",  
        method:"POST",  
        data:{vehicle_id:vehicle_id},  
        success:function(data){ 
            modal.find('.modal-body').html('No Response');
            modal.find('.modal-body').html(data);
             $('#vehicle_detail').html(data);  
             $('#dataModal').modal("show");  
        }  
   });  
});   
</script>
```